# Extract characters from a cell with format h:mm

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract

*I use Excel in spanish.

I have a cell with format `h:mm (A1 = 07:35)`, and I want to extract the first two characters in one column `(B1=07)`, and the others into a different one `(C1=35)`.

When I apply the EXTRACT formula `(B1=EXTRAE(A1;1;2), C1=EXTRAE(A1;4;2))`, it does not throw the numbers that I ask, because of the format, the formula only recognize TEXT format, not h:mm (it shows `B1=0`, and `C1=30`, because `A1=0,330555556` in text format).

What formula does what I want or how can I get the numbers that I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your time is stored as text, you will need to parse it somehow. In the simplest case, you can use `IZQUIERDA()` and `DERECHA()` to get the leftmost or rightmost characters respectively.
`=IZQUIERDA(A1,2)` and `=DERECHA(A1,2)`

If your times are stored as a date, you should use
`=MINUTO(A1)` and `=HORA(A1)`

However, if you have a more complex date and are unable to use VBA, you'll have to perform some sort of evil splitting to find it.. For example:

**A1**

```
Event 07:35 am
```

**B1 Hour**

```
=IZQUIERDA(RDERECHA(A1,LEN(A1)-SI.ERROR(HALLAR(" ??:??",A1)+1,HALLAR(" ?:??",A1))),HALLAR(":",RDERECHA(A1,LEN(A1)-SI.ERROR(HALLAR(" ??:??",A1)+1,HALLAR(" ?:??",A1))))-1)
```

**C1 Minute** which depends on the Hour to function

```
=IZQUIERDA(RDERECHA(A1,LEN(A1)-HALLAR(B10&":",A1)-1),2)
```

Here's my attempt at an example demonstration
[image: Excel Spanish Dates Example]

Disclaimer: the Spanish translations of formulas are according to [this internet source](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-spanish.html)

Answer (score 1):

EXTRAE is a version of MID() function in English and MID function works on text values as you indicated. So first convert the cell into a text value and then extract
=MID(TEXT(A1, "hh:mm"), 1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

From your example I believe you are try to extract the Hour and the Minute components of a time. If you want the Hour or Minute of a time value use the `=HOUR(A1)` Function for extracting the hour and the `=MINUTE(A1)` Function for extracting the minute.

Format the cells to be 00 so that the cells show two digits for values below 10.

Don't know their equivalent functions in Spanish but hopefully that gives you a point in the right direction.